# In which situation is better to use fixed size layouts in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I always use match_parent or wrap_content in width and/or height and I work with margin and padding (depending I use 0dp on height when I use the weight of Linear Layout) to adjust my layout depending on my needs.

I read that it is the correct way to work if I am developing for any size of android screens.

Is there any situation that is better to use fixed size in the android layout?

Comment: I sent this question because I have doubts about this. I think this is useful for every Android developer. It's something good for every developer (even if you has this in the documentation). Why give a down vote to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a specific hardware target that you'll run on, fixed sizes are easier to get everything to line up perfectly.  If you want things to be a certain physical size (such as exactly 2 inches big) dp is the best way of doing things.  There's a few use cases, but it should generally be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gabe.
I imagined in that case can be use.
Generally I avoid to use fixed size.

Answer (score 1):

I found one [example](http://radleymarx.com/blog/15-quirky-android-xml-layout-parameters-to-know/) which suggests one such scenario :

> The common setting for stretchable layouts is  layout_width / layout_height set to match_parent. But when you want it to fit around another container, the Android sdk recommends you use 0dip instead of match_parent. I recommend using 0dip so it’s easier to differentiate partial layouts from full-size layouts.

But, according to android [wiki](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)  you should avoid using fixed values.

> In general, specifying a layout width and height using absolute units such as pixels is not recommended. Instead, using relative measurements such as density-independent pixel units (dp), wrap_content, or match_parent, is a better approach, because it helps ensure that your application will display properly across a variety of device screen sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Zeus.
This will help a lot.